# Самый быстрый способ сделать request

Tags: python, api, requests

мне надо послать 2 request'а в чёткое время. Максимальная погрешность - не более 100 мс. Как добиться такого(или максимально приближённого) результата? С обычной библиотекой requests получается слишком медленно, даже на VPS'е. Буду благодарен любой помощи. Если что, то делаю .put.

Comment: Нужно быть четким) Может быть отправляете не четко, а медленно. Без кода не понять.

Comment: Второй запрос зависит от первого? Если нет, то можно асинхронно/многопоточно сделать

Comment: QNX надо накатить видимо, чтобы четко все было

Comment: К примеру, я хочу, чтобы request был послан ровно в 21:16:30.00. Мне именно важна точность

Comment: Ну сделайте два потока, пусть они ждут назначенного времени и отправляют запрос вовремя. А вообще это же зависит от раутинга и т.д., мало ли какие проблемы у вашего провайдера, куда у него раутинг идёт.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вы можете взглянуть в сторону модуля под названием [Tornado](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/).**

Tornado - это веб-фреймворк для Python, асинхронная сетевая библиотека, первоначально разработанная FriendFeed. Благодаря Tornado вы можете одновременно отправлять вплоть до 10000 запросов.

Простейший пример из [официальной документации](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/):

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```